# Git integration For Magento2

Tags: magento2, git, github

I committed my project files from one development member finely. When another developer tried to pull files and push his changes to git. It is adding some code. For example bootstrap.php file the following 
**<<<<< HEAD is added**.

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
=======
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
ini_set("track_errors", 1);
ini_set("html_errors", 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
>>>>>>> 8ee88031045329aa9e3793e7ee1352f9750118c1
```

How to remove these <<<<<

We are following below commands to commit files in git.

```
git init

git config --global user.email "myemail@gmail.com"

git remote add origin https://web.com/web.git

git config --global http.sslverify false

git push --set-upstream origin master

git pull --rebase

git pull https://web.com/web.git master

git pull origin master --allow-unrelated-histories
```

It is a private repo. What was wrong in these commands.? Please help me.